# JSON parsing and security

Tags: javascript, python, json, security

Our infrastructure is using Python for everything in the backend and Javascript for our "front-end" (it's a library we serve to other sites). The communication between the different components of the infrastructure is done via JSON messages.

In Python, `json.load()` and `json.dump()` are a safe way of dealing with a JSON string. In Javascript, `JSON.parse()` would be use instead. But, these functions only guarantee that the string has a proper JSON format, am I right?

If I'm concerned about injection attacks, I would need to sanitize every field of the JSON by other means. Am I right in this assumption? Or just by using the previously mentioned functions we would be safe?

Comment: Any input in any format has to be handled properly to prevent injections. Using the correct methods to parse JSON is one part. But this does not allow your to go without other input validation and quoting or escaping. And SQL injection can happen in a string store in a valid JSON object.

Comment: JSON values can only be numbers, strings, booleans, and `null`, or objects/arrays of those. All you ever get out of `JSON.parse()` is a simple value, not code.

Comment: What sort of attacks exactly are you worried about...?

Comment: @deceze "If I'm concerned about injection attacks"

Comment: "Injection attacks" of what sort? JSON-injection? Probably not. SQL injection? What's that doing on the client side? HTML injection? Certainly that's entirely divorced from JSON and must certainly be handled wherever your data comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as sanitized and unsanitized data, without context.

Data is only considered unsafe if user controlled data is used in a context where it has special meaning.

e.g. `'` in SQL, and `<script>` in HTML.

Contrary to `<script>` in SQL, which is completely safe.

The upshot is to encode/sanitize when the data is used, not when it is received from JSON.

Answer (score 5):

`JSON.parse` will throw an exception if the input string is not in valid JSON format.
It is safe to use, I can't think of any way to attack your code with just JSON.parse. It does not work like `eval`.

Of course you can check the resulting json object to make sure it has the structure you're expecting.

Comment: User input from JSON.parse() is a potential vector for prototype poisoning per this article: https://medium.com/intrinsic/javascript-prototype-poisoning-vulnerabilities-in-the-wild-7bc15347c96